# How do you delete all text above a certain line

Tags: vim

How do you delete all text above a certain line. For deletion below a line I use "d shift g"

Answer (score 615, accepted):

```
dgg
```

will delete everything from your current line to the top of the file.

`d` is the deletion command, and `gg` is a movement command that says go to the top of the file, so when used together, it means delete from my current position to the top of the file.

Also

```
dG
```

will delete all lines at or below the current one

Comment: And kdgg will do the same except not delete the line in question.

Comment: What exactly does the `gg` after delete mean?

Comment: gg is a Vim shortcut - ":help gg" says:  Goto line [count], default first line, on the first non-blank character |linewise|.  If  startofline' not set, keep the same column.

Comment: For those looking for it, `dG` will delete all lines at or below the current one.

Comment: @dan3 I think the meaning of "top of the file" is pretty clear based on the question asked, but you are welcome to edit my answer if you want to, or you can create your own answer using whatever terminology you want.

Comment: Worth noting that this won't get rid of everything from the beginning of the file to the current line. I'm not sure whether it's all unprintable characters, or just some specific things (like random numbers), but I know that it won't erase the UTF-8 BOM from a file (0xefbbbf). So, it's not perfect. Found that out the annoying way. Most of the time, of course, it's fine.

Comment: `dgg <========= This is the answer`

Answer (score 45):

`:1,.d` deletes lines 1 to current.
`:1,.-1d` deletes lines 1 to above current.

(Personally I'd use `dgg` or `kdgg` like the other answers, but TMTOWTDI.)

Comment: I tried `TMTOWTDI` but it just seems to leave me in insert mode without deleting anything?

Comment: TMTOWTDI is not one of the More Than One Ways To Do It.

Comment: tmtowtdi
There's more than one way to do it (TMTOWTDI or TIMTOWTDI, pronounced "Tim Toady") is a Perl motto.

Comment: @toomuchphp The comment was fantastic. But the username... that made it perfect. +1 to you.

Comment: Thanks.  Surprisingly, `:1,.d` works in Busybox vi v1.29, but `dgg` does not.

Answer (score 42):

```
kdgg
```

delete all lines above the current one.

Comment: This is a little confusing; it's actually moving the cursor up a line with `k`, then deleting the current line and up with `dgg`.

Comment: And use 5kdgg to delete all lines 5 lines above the current one ;)

Answer (score 11):

Providing you know these vim commands:

```
1G -> go to first line in file
G -> go to last line in file
```

then, the following make more sense, are more unitary and easier to remember IMHO:

```
d1G -> delete starting from the line you are on, to the first line of file
dG -> delete starting from the line you are on, to the last line of file
```

Cheers.

Comment: "g isn't a vi command" because
g is an extension, G is more compatible

Answer (score 8):

`d1G`  = delete to top including current line (vi)

Answer (score 1):

`:.,$-3d` deletes from current line to 3 lines from end